# How do to visualize with Matplotlib's basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, matplotlib-basemap

I have tried to visualize the global cases of corona on a map using folium.circle how do I implement the same with matplotlib's basemap module.

currently my code looks like this:

```
x = data[['Confirmed']].values.astype(float)

# Create a minimum and maximum processor object
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

# Create an object to transform the data to fit minmax processor
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)

# Run the normalizer on the dataframe
df_normalized = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)

df_normalized.columns = 'norm_dat'.split()
data['norm_con'] = df_normalized['norm_dat'].values

world_map = folium.Map(location=[35.0,105.0], zoom_start=2.3,tiles='CartoDB dark_matter')

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    folium.Circle(
                          location=[data.iloc[i]['Latitude'], data.iloc[i]['Longitude']],
                          popup=data.iloc[i]['State'],
                          radius=(data.iloc[i]['norm_con'])*1000000,
                          color='red',
                          fill=True,
                          fill_color='crimson'

                           ).add_to(world_map)




world_map
```

[output map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfhCc.png)